# How to check detect signalR version used on client browser?

Tags: signalr

How to detect which signalR version has been used on client browser side?

`$.connection.conferenceHub.version`? (this does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got the answer to check which signalR version is used on client:**

`$.signalR.version`